# Наклонение в СПП сравнения

Tags: наклонение

*Она вела себя так, **словно была моей женой**.*

В моем анализе все предложения в оригинале содержат сослагательное наклонение после итальянского союза *come se*.
Все эти предложения переведены на русский через индикатив. 
Как можно объяснить использование индикатива в русском, если речь идет о гипотетических сравнениях, которые в реальном мире не имели место?

В анализе есть только один пример с сосл. наклонением:

*Она слушала его внимательно, **как если бы слушала оперу**.*

Не понимаю, почему в первом случае используется индикатив (если она НЕ являлась его женой), а во втором стоит сосл. наклонение?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Вы несколко раз задавали однотипные вопросы, если у вас проблема с оценкой качества перевода, давайте исходный текст, что мы гадаем-то? Или идите к переводчикам. Если вы не подвергаете перевод сомнению, то в чем вообще ваша задача? Разобраться со способами выражения ирреального условия в русском? Для этого не надо столько примеров, найдите доступный учебник русской грамматики, репетитора наймите в конце концов...

Comment: Диссертацию на тему "сравнительный анализ функций конъюнктива и способов его выражения в русском и итальянском языках" вам тут не напишут. Нет специалистов.

Comment: Дорогой Behemothus, спасибо Вам за Ваши ценные советы про книгу и репетитора! Написать диссертацию я никого не просила. Просто когда появляются мне непонятные моменты, я здесь задаю вопросы. По-моему для этого и сделали этот форум, или нет? А если Вас мои однотипные вопросы гневят, пролистывайте или проходите дальше! + Спасибо за ответ на вопрос!!!

Comment: Вы действительно пишете диссертацию? Бегемот угадал?

Comment: *Вы действительно пишете диссертацию? Бегемот угадал?*  - да нет, я образно выразился. Для диссертации это слишком, материал на форуме собирать, не имея теоретической базы. Диплом, может, какой-то или курсовую. Но явно ж, не ради спортивного интереса. ))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что семантику сослагательного наклонения в данном случае передают союзы СЛОВНО, БУДТО, КАК ЕСЛИ БЫ. Эти союзы относятся к группе вероятностных, недостоверных, поэтому нет необходимости в дополнительном использовании формы  сослагательного наклонения для глагола.

Comment: большое спасибо! : )

Answer (score 3):

> Не понимаю, почему в первом случае используется индикатив (если она НЕ
>   являлась его женой), а во втором стоит сосл. наклонение?

Я не вижу в ваших примерах фразы с семантикой "***если*** она ***не являлась*** его женой".

По грамматике фразы очень близки, если не тождественны. 
"Как если бы" составной союз, синоним для "словно", причем едва ли не абсолютный.

Сослагательное наклонение тут вообще ни при чем, частица "бы" сама по себе потеряла тут функцию сослагательности, если вообще имела, эта выражение  условности события перешло на весь союз ("как если бы" < "как есть ли быхъ") т.е. по современному "как было бы", "как будто бы". Во первом же примере эту роль полностью реализует союз "словно".